# include class files from another directory, php

Tags: php

Trying to make a file structure for `class`, `api` and etc. But when I try to include a class into `api/` file, problem happens... it's look like I can't give the file path's correctly. But couldn't find what is wrong.

the directory and file structure is like image below.

[image]

**Insert class**

```
class Insert extends Dbc {

    public function getProjects(){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM projects";
        $stmt = $this->connect()->query($sql);
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
            $row["project_name"] . "<br>";
        }

    }

}
```

**autoload inc**

```
spl_autoload_register('autoloader');

function autoloader($className){
    $path = "classes/";
    $extension = ".class.php";
    $fullPath = $path . $className . $extension;

    if (!file_exists($fullPath)) {
        return false;
    }

    include_once $fullPath;
}
```

and finally, `/api` file **projects.api**

```
<?php 
    include "../inc/autoload.inc.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
            $projects = new Insert(); 
            echo $projects->getProjects(); 

    ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

But here is the thing I am getting a 500 error. AND when I use try and catch on `$projects = new Insert();` in api file. It says can't find the `class`... It means `include "../inc/autoload.inc.php";` not working correctly?

Comment: Have you tried using composer? Its a easy/good way to handle namespaces/multiple folders structures

Comment: Actually, i didn't because I am on shared hosting. and can't use the ssh access.  @TurqSpl

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. The mistake was I didn't include the class inside the autoload file. So it doesn't find the class.. Here is the new `autoload.inc.php`

```
spl_autoload_register('autoloader');

include "../classes/insert.class.php";

function autoloader($className){
    $path = "../classes/";
    $extension = ".class.php";
    $fullPath = $path . $className . $extension;

    if (!file_exists($fullPath)) {
        return false;
    }

    include_once $fullPath;
}
```